# How can I verify that my Google Developer API is at V3?

Tags: android, google-developers-console, google-console-developer, google-developer-tools

I got email from Google saying “Action required: Migrate to v3 of the Developer API by December 1". The details can be found here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html.

I found that we are using V2 in the backend. My questions are:

1. How can I be sure that my app is no longer calling V2? From what I see, I could be using other third-party library that's calling V1 or V2. Is there a place in Google Developer Console I can check to make sure?
2. I am also using many Google libraries in my Android App. Is there a way to know if they are using V3? It would be a pain to update all of them to the latest.